# Remapping an external url to an internal port service

Tags: apache, jetty

I've tagged this Apache as I think that's what I'm looking for, but I understand I am about to be educated. Feel free to edit the question title if I've missed the mark.

I have a home server (Linux Mint 13, LAMP stack) running several services through http. For example:

```
[MY-IP]/        <- landing
[MY-IP]/service1    
[MY-IP]/service2
[MY-IP]/service3
```

I also run Subsonic (a music server, subsonic.org), which runs on port 4040.

```
[MY-IP]:4040/           <- subsonic landing page
[MY-IP]:4040/index.view <- example subsonic page
```

Subsonic has a bundled Jetty (java) server listening on port 4040.

I want to get rid of the port declaration; can I use apache to forward some port 80 calls to port 4040, when a specific directory/url is hit? For example:

```
[MY-IP]/subsonic
```

internally redirects to

```
[MY-IP]:4040/
```

meaning that I can use

```
[MY-IP]/subsonic/index.view
```

A lot of places (my workplace, for example) block use of non-strandard ports [though personal music is allowed, so I'm not breaking any rules] - I want a simple URL to use, both for myself and so that my girlfriend can access the music.

Can this be done with virtual hosts in apache, or with mod_rewrite, without impacting my normal port 80 services? If apache isn't the method, how can I achieve my stated goal?

(this is all for external access to a server behind a router, port forwarding is not an issue)

Links to an explicit guide would be useful; my google-fu has fallen short on this one.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your looking for mod_proxy: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html